# EaselJS/canvas - how to draw figure B after figure A, so that figure B is "under" figure A

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, easeljs

I have been working on this game for a few days now. One of the last problems I am facing is this:

When the player moves out of the border moving area (see picture below) the "line" is drawn behind him - he creates some kind of a wall (see directed arrows on the picture).

After this, he is able to move on this wall, BUT you cannot see the player (small red rectangle), until he moves right (in this case) to the white area.

You can see that the player can be seen when he is positioned on the gray border walls, but these walls were created **before** the player was created.

How should I change the rendering here to be able to see the player on the area that was drawn **after** the player? Do I need to redraw everything to be able to get it the way I need it?

[image]

Any suggestions highly appreciated. If I was not clear enough, let me know so I can explain it better.

Thanks

Comment: maybe using AddChildAt instead of AddChild when inserting your player could do the job.

Comment: Wow! I actually changed stage.addChild(rect) to stage.addChildAt(rect,0) for each rectangle that I draw (line is made of rectangles) and it works! post this as an answer and I can accept it!

Comment: I didn't know addChildAt exists even. What documentation do you use for this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EasleJs will by default consider the objects just pile up in the order you provide them.
Yet, you can use AddChildAt to control the 'z' of your objects and avoid the issue.

Since the draw order is something that has to be handle at the stage, (not child), level, just have a look at the official documentation on Stage :

http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Stage.html